# How opencart language works

Tags: php, opencart

A english.php language file in opencart looks like this.

```
 $_['date_format_short']     = 'd/m/Y';
 $_['date_format_long']      = 'l dS F Y';
 ...
 and so on
```

I want to know how how is this implemented with php, are they somehow extracting all variables for later use like $date_format_short or it's a convention for some sort of global variable.

How can i implement a language system that generates these variables from $_['date_format_short'] to $date_format_short.

Comment: `$date_format_short = $_['date_format_short']`? `$_` is simply a variable (albeit a poorly name one), nothing special about it. This would be no different than any other associative array like `$localization['date_format_short']`.

Comment: how can i make it "special"?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  What does "make it special" mean?  I have no idea about opencart, but my guess is that upon selecting a language to use, it just includes the appropriate localization file, which provides the array named `$_`. Why do you want to extract key-value pairs from this array into a bunch of individual variables?

Comment: if you have no idea about opencart, then why did you answered? my question was "I want to know how how is this implemented with php".

Comment: Your question was asking about how this is implemented in PHP, and whether `$_` had any special significance to the PHP language.  I simply comment that `$_` is just a variable with no special scope or behaviors associated.  It seems from your question you were trying to understand how you could implement a system to extract individual variables from this array.  Your question did not mention at all that you wanted to understand how opencart uses this variable, or loads localization information or anything like like. I was just commenting to help to figure out what you were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language variables don't actually get extracted. They are merely merged into an array in `system/library/language.php` with any other language file loads. The values that do get extracted are the `$this->data` array in a controller, which are extracted in the file `system/engine/controller.php` in the `render()` method